# When to use Depth-first search

Tags: python, list, sorting, depth-first-search

So I want to sort a range of numbers so that the sum of every sequential number is a squared number (4,9,16,25,...) I was told I should use Depth first search but am unable to implenment it correctly, especialy the backtracking part. Is this the correct way to do this, what am I not seeing, doing wrong? Is DFS even the correct way to do this?

```
class Node:                         #Define node Object
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value         #Node "Name"
        self.adjacentNodes=list()  #Node Neighbours

#Set limit
limit=16
squares=list() #list for squared numbers in rang smaller than 2Xlimit
tree=list() #Tree containing nodes
path=list() #current path taken

def calculate(limit):   #Population control legal squares
    for i in range(1,(limit+1)):
        i=i*i
        if i<(limit+limit):
            squares.append(i)

calculate(limit)    #Populate squares list

for a in range(1,(limit+1)): #creating the nodes
    newnode=Node(a)
    for s in squares:
        legalsum=s-a
        if legalsum>0 and legalsum<limit and legalsum!=a: #zero and lower can't play,keeping non-exiting nodes out of node.adjacentNodes, don't connect to selve.
            newnode.adjacentNodes.append(legalsum)  #Add adjacentnode
    tree.append(newnode)    #add newborn to tree

for b in range(0,limit):
    print tree[b].value,tree[b].adjacentNodes #Quick checkup
#Now the tree is build and can be used to search for paths.
'''
Take a node and check adjnodes
is it already visited? check path
yes-> are all nodes visited (loop over tree(currentnode).adjnodes) Maybe use len()
        yes->pop last node from path and take other node -> fear for infinte loops, do I need a current node discard pile?
        no -> visit next available adje node next in line from loop got from len(tree.adjn)
no-> take this as node and check adj nodes.

'''
def dfs (node):
    path.append(node)
    #load/check adjacent nodes
    tree[node].adjacentNodes
    for adjnode in tree[node-1].adjacentNodes:
        if adjnode in path:
            #skip to next adj node
            continue


        else:
            print path #Quick checkup
            dfs(adjnode)
dfs(8)    # start with 8 since 1-16 should be {8,1,15,10,6,3,13,12,4,5,11,14,2,7,9,16}
```

Comment: huh that doesnt make sense ? how can you sort `[1,2,34,5,6,7,8,9]` by those conditions?

Comment: What is `#load/check adjacent nodes` supposed to be doing? You're just referencing a list and then ignoring it. If this is some kind of cache- or VM-preloading optimization, even if it's useful, surely it doesn't belong in an example you're still trying to understand and debug…

Comment: Also, you're writing a recursive function that doesn't `return` anything, doesn't print anything out except some temporary debugging output, and doesn't mutate anything except to keep a list of all the nodes it's walked through (which, if your tree is actually a tree, or even a connected non-tree graph, and you do the DFS right, is guaranteed to be all the nodes), so… what's the point of that?

Comment: And speaking of the non-tree bit: Why `if adjnode in path`? If the tree is a tree, it can't have any cycles. So, the only thing you're checking is "has this function ever been called before?" (because after it's called the first time, every node will be in `path`), and surely there are easier (a single flag) or more useful (a memoization cache) things you could do instead.

Comment: ... I think you need to go back and look at simple dfs traversal to a goal state with a simple tree... there are several issues with your code ... I'll try and provide some direction in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are talking about with the squares but here are some problems

```
def dfs (node):
    #always assume the path starts with this node
    path=[node]
    if node == GoalState: return path #we win!!
    #load/check adjacent nodes
    #this line did nothing `tree[node].adjacentNodes`
    for adjnode in tree[node-1].adjacentNodes:
    # if adjnode in path: ****this will never be true, lets eliminate it
    #         #skip to next adj node
    #        continue

    #   else:
            subpath = dfs(adjnode)
            if subpath and subpath.endswith(GoalState): 
               return path + subpath #return solution

    #if we get here there is no solution from this node to the goal state
```

Comment: I think the tree is not actually a tree, but rather an undirected graph, so protection against cycles will be needed. I'd suggest passing in the path so far as an argument!

Comment: ehh then you have explored and frontier to manage them ... but he said tree and kept using tree in his code (I suspected it was an undirected graph as well ... but I figured I would adress his question based on that ... ) He clearly needs to grasp DFS better before moving on to posibilities of cycles